# Preview file from original file is bigger in size android bitmap

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, android-bitmap

Given a file (which of course is an Image) in Android i want to make a preview image which of course should be smaller in size. I use the code below

```
     override fun createImagePreview(serverId: Long, fileName: String) {
        if (fileName.fileType() != IMAGE_TYPE) return

        val file = serverDir.getFileByName(fileName)
        val originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath) ?: return

        var newWidth = DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE.toDouble()
        var newHeight = DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE.toDouble()

        if (originalBitmap.width > originalBitmap.height) {
            val ratio = originalBitmap.width / originalBitmap.height
            newHeight = newWidth / ratio
        } else if (originalBitmap.width < originalBitmap.height) {
            val ratio = originalBitmap.height / originalBitmap.width
            newWidth = newHeight / ratio
        }

        val bmp = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(
            originalBitmap,
            newWidth.toInt().dpToPixel(appContext),
            newHeight.toInt().dpToPixel(appContext)
        )

        FileOutputStream(File(serverDir, "p_$fileName")).use {
            it.write(bmp.toByteArray())
            it.flush()
        }
    }
```

However, i see inside my internalStorage that if the File is 5KB then the PreviewFile is 19KB. What is wrong with that?

Comment: `Given a file (which of course is an Image)` Of course. But why not tell if it is a jpg or png or whatever? Makes a big difference if you compare.

Comment: Further you did not tell the image file type of resulting file.

Comment: `bmp.toByteArray())` Could you tell what the content of that byte array would be? All pixels? A jpg? A png? I think all pixels.

Comment: Hm...well i dont know but its for sure an Image. However, is there a solution that could be universal? Besides i transform it to Bitmap, so does this really matter? :/

Answer (score 0):

bmp.toByteArray is the wrong way to store an image.  The Bitmap object is uncompressed.  That means it uses 4 bytes per pixel.  A jpg or png is compressed, that means it uses less data per pixel.  You want to store it in one of those formats.  The way to do that is to use Bitmap.compress() and pass it a stream to the file you want to use.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer! Can you please give me a snippet of code because i didn't get it all..?